# NVIDIA DRIVER for LG A530-U.BE54P1(5466)

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install NVIDIA's proprietary driver in my laptop:
LG A530-U.BE54P1(5466)
I installed it and when i try to log in, it shows the screen in low resolution. After log in, it shows a black screen.
My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 13.10.
How can i solve it? Which informations do you need to analise it? Thank you!

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to these. if it is older versions of nvidia graphics cards, you can also try using bumblebee.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia